# Save file dialog box to appear after a MySQL data export (using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, csv, dialog, save

I have found many "partial" answers to questions similar to this, but I'm new to PHP and MySQL and there doesn't seem to be one nice big coherent answer out there; What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Get all the data from a MySQL table called "producers".
2. Have the user select a filename/'save as' location on their local machine.
3. PHP / MySQL / HTML gets the data and writes to it as a CSV file.

Parts 1 and 3 are easy; but getting a way for the user to select a file location/filename seems to be nigh on impossible. It's simple in HTML for a user to select a file for upload, so why is it so hard for me to find a way for a user to select a "save" location/name? Surely this is not a security risk - downloading from a server is far less of a security risk than uploading something to a server.

I'd like to be able to use the nice and simple MySQL method, but I don't know how to just send this command from PHP to MySQL; just putting it in a mysqli_query doesn't seem to do anything:

```
SELECT prodCompany,prodPhone,prodFirstname FROM producers
INTO OUTFILE '/Users/me/Desktop/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

(this method works fine from within phpMyAdmin).

So I've gone for the clunky step by step PHP method for now, which works, but obviously only ever saves "file.csv" to my desktop. I have read the odd mention of MIME types, but I'm not sure how this could help me and how to implement it.

All I want is to trigger a file selector dialog box, to get that filepath/name into the $filename variable. But after a couple of days of frustration, I cannot find anything that works. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

- Paul

The PHP that saves to that one file:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

$filename = '/Users/me/Desktop/file.csv';
$headers = array('prodCompany', 'prodPhone', 'prodFirstname');

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
fputcsv($handle, $headers, ',', '"');

$sql = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM producers');

while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $row = array(
        $results['prodCompany'],
        $results['prodPhone'],
        $results['prodFirstname']
    );
    fputcsv($handle, $row, ',', '"');
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: Actually, it is a security risk. If the browser could write to any directory then javascript could write to any directory. I think that is true.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - I didn't realise that allowing a user to choose a file could potentially allow javacsript write access. Matt, what if the file doesn't yet exist (it's being created "on the fly")? Might it be better (if possible) to have MySQL first create the file on the server, and once that process has finished, THEN have the download/file selection process start?

Comment: @MattThompson, but can you set the download location from a program running on the browser or does the user have to at least respond to the download prompt?

Comment: @MattThompson, it is not the user responding to prompts that is the issue with the question asked. They wants to programmatically set the file destination and bypass the user prompt. That is the scary bit.

Comment: Ideally, I'd make a "save dialog box" appear, the user chooses a location/types in a filename, and all that happens is that the filepath is put into the $filename variable. Then the rest of the PHP does the actual saving. My current PHP (shown in the original post) works perfectly (is this "force writing to a client"?) but only ever saves that one file in that one location. Is it not possible to somehow trigger a "save dialog box" without the browser actually saving something?

Comment: @paul, 'pre-loading' a filename into the 'save' dialogue box is not a good idea. Users read what they expect to see and just push 'go'. It would be easy to 'trick' a user into writing a nasty file somewhere that it shouldn't. Also, you cannot do this from your PHP it would have to be javascript running on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ryan and Matt for all your help. Looks like I'll have to research using javascript to do the filename stuff. Hopefully it'll be reasonably straightforward!

Comment: Haha...silly me..."reasonably straightforward!". Do I sense a hint of sarcasm in your smiley, Ryan? All I want to do is bring up a file selector, but this seems to be beyond the technical capabilities of 21st Century computing, without resorting to swf, APIs, and years of programming experience. How very annoying. (Sorry for the rant...)

Comment: no, no sarcasm ever! I really do mean enjoy the research and learning! I really like programming - it is fun! Look, learning is a journey - it is the the exploration that is fun - the end result, well that depends on what you find on the journey. You must enjoy the journey. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the concept being you want to generate a csv and have the user save it.

Form to get file name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="test" action="csv_gen.php" method="post">
    <label for="filename">File name </label>
  <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go get file" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Script to process and force csv download

```
<?php
if($_POST) {

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_POST['filename'].'.csv');

    //replace this with whatever generates your csv and print it
    echo "field1,field2,field3,field4,field5\n";

}
?>
```

This will do the force download. With newer browsers that have a default download location, such as Chrome, this will download the file immediately using whatever file name a user enters into the form field. They would then open that location and move the file. That is pretty standard browser functionality that I wouldn't try to overwrite. It might confuse people that have a default location set for downloads.

Hopefully that helps get you started.

Comment: Ah - I figured out what I was doing wrong...it took me a while to figure out that the PHP script is pure PHP - I had it embedded in an HTML page and that broke stuff. I'd tried some earlier suggestions about using header('Content-Type... with no success. I hadn't seen it pointed out anywhere that this process seemingly must not be used within some HTML. And thanks once again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar problem in a one file php app where all forms submit to the same index.php.  After submitting the form, I did the following:

1. Re-fetched the database results
2. Used fopen to create a file called 'out.csv' somewhere on the server
3. Wrote each row of the result set to out.csv
4. Redirected to out.csv with: `header("Location: relative_path_to_csv/out.csv");`

The default save dialog appears the same way it would if you were to make a link to the file and click on it.

The drawback is that if it's called concurrently by multiple users, that same 'out.csv' would be overwritten by others.  The solution to that is to use a unique identifier for the file name and have some process to periodically clean out the csv directory (cron job).